# pass parameter between each function

Tags: jquery, oop

I'm trying to make code reusable , this is what I practice wrap code in an object learning oop, how to pass the data `response` to `handleErros()`  but I get console.log response undefined? any suggestion how to solve it?

```
Core.init();

var Core = function() {

    handleErrors = function(response) {
        var Errors = response.Errors;
        // console.log('length'+Errors.length);

        var i;
        for (i = 0; i < Errors.length; ++i) {
            var Error = '<div>'+Errors[i]+'</div>';
            $('.ajax-error-panel').append(Error);
        }
        $('.ajax-error-panel').show();
    };

    ajaxpost = function() {
       ... ajax...
       .done(function(response){
            handleErrors(response);
        });
    };

    ...

    return {
        handleErrors(response);
        ajaxpost();
    }

}();
```

Comment: try with self.handleError(response)

Comment: shows can't find variable: response  on line return { handleErros...

Comment: return only `ajaxpost();`.

Comment: @user1775888 glad this worked, just added an answer to it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

change this:

```
return {
    handleErrors(response);
    ajaxpost();
}
```

to this:

```
return {
    ajaxpost();
}
```

---

Because ajax is asynchronous and at the time, when you return the `handleErrors(response);` the response is undefined because this doesn't hold anything.